# Is there a way to use .htaccess in php cli?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have setup a folder as a temporary development server thru

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

Everything is working fine, that is, except the .htaccess settings. I saw from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983348/do-htaccess-php-value-settings-affect-scripts-run-at-command-line/983367#983367) that .htaccess is used only by apache. Is there a way for php cli to use it ?

Comment: No there is no way. You can try wget or curl instead direct php. that way you will use httpd instead

Comment: **Some** of what's possible via `.htaccess` is conceivably possible to do with the PHP development server, but you'd have to be specific on what you're trying to do.

Comment: See also https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/12/22/php-5-4-htrouter-your-personal-apache-2-2-compatible-server/ and https://github.com/jaytaph/htrouter, or check out [Nanowebs mod_rewrite](https://github.com/markkimsal/nanoweb-ssl/blob/master/modules/mod_rewrite.php) (needs some customization for this though).

Comment: @ceejayoz I was looking to clean urls. Something like instead of using `http://example.com/index.php?q=param1` , use `http://example.com/param1` . I see it's working when I copy the folder into `/var/www` , but its not working when I setup the folder as `localhost:8080`

Comment: @mario thanks for the suggestion, though I am still unable to launch the specified server properly. probably a problem with the HTRouter script .